# There is an annoying warning prop `error` on <img> tag in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks

I am getting a warning as below, how can we get rid of this warning.

> Warning: Invalid value for prop `error` on  tag. Either remove it
>   from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the
>   DOM. For details, 
>       in img (at Profile.js:79)
>       in div (at Profile.js:78)
>       in div (at Profile.js:73)
>       in div (at Profile.js:72)
>       in form (at Profile.js:69)
>       in div (at Profile.js:68)
>       in div (at Profile.js:67)
>       in div (at Profile.js:66)
>       in Profile (created by Context.Consumer)
>       in Route (at App.js:21)
>       in Switch (at App.js:20)
>       in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>       in BrowserRouter (at App.js:17)
>       in App (at src/index.js:11)
>       in StrictMode (at src/index.js:10)
>       in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>       in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:9

*

```
<div className="previewProfilePic" >
    <img alt="" error={addDefaultSrc} name="previewImage" className="playerProfilePic_home_tile" src= 
    {photo} onChange={e => handleChange(e, id)}></img>
</div>
```

Code added for `addDefaultSrc`

```
 const addDefaultSrc = e => {
    e.target.src = '/images/default-icon.png';
  }
```

Comment: You need to use `onError` prop not `error`

Comment: Solved that problem